# Qml MediaPlayer loads video faster than audio

Tags: android, qt, audio, video, qml

I have a qml file with a MediaPlayer. MediaPlayer loads remote urls from a web server, which can be video (mp4, 260p) or audio (mp3) files.

But surprisingly, a video is loaded and downloaded faster than an audio.
Usually video takes 4-5 seconds to start, but audio varies between 5-50 seconds!

Is this a Qt/Qml issue? or a web server?

PS: I don't have access to web server and I am running application on android device.

Comment: Maybe you have 10M video and 100M audio files? Post your working code and links so we could test that.

Comment: Surely you can test with a webserver of your own to investigate the issue. You can host one on your dev machine.

Comment: @folibis audio files are much smaller than video.
Also mention that, this issue is on android 6, with or without using OpenSSL

Comment: @GrecKo local with web server, there is no delay in loading